# How to print the output of a command to a new window in vim

Tags: vim

When I execute a command like this:

```
:g/FIXME/p
```

It prints the matching lines in the section where I wrote my code. I want to process output of this command more, so I manually select the output text in gvim, open a new split window and paste manually. However, if the output is too big, I cannot do copy&paste easily.

Is there a way to push output of commands into a new window automatically? I.e. what I want to do is something like this:

```
:g/FIXME/print_to_new_window
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing with those results?

Comment: @romainl, I want to do anything that you can do in vim: write, delete, find&replace, duplicate etc. Do you have different answers depending on modifications I'd do afterwards?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to find all matched lines in your buffer and paste to a new window/buffer, you can do this:

```
:let @a=''|g/FIXME/y A
```

This line will save all matched (contains `FIXME`)  lines in register `a`.

Now you can open a window, E.g. `:vnew` then paste the content from `a`

```
"ap
```

Well if you really want to save the output of a command, you will have to use `:redir` command, check the help (`:h :redir`) for details, it is well explained.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using the quickfix window to store your match results.  There's some information about this on the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_using_quickfix_to_list_occurrences).  The example there shows how to match the current word under the cursor, but you could use something like this:

`vim
command! -nargs=1 GREP :execute 'vimgrep '.string(<q-args>).' '.expand('%') | :copen | :cc`

Then a `GREP FIXME` would pop-open the matches in a quickfix window, which is great for navigating between the results.  Here's what it could look like:

[image: quickfix]

This was a result of running `:GREP fnamemodify` in one of my vim files.

Comment: Good solution but I guess it needs a couple of more tweaks. It is opening it in a quickfix list, which is not modifiable by default. And it prints filename and position of the match, which I don't need.

Comment: You don't really state your purpose in the question, so I wasn't sure if you were trying to actually modify stuff or not.  You might be interested in the [quickfix reflector](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim) though.  You can make changes in the quickfix window and have it update the files.  It's rather slick.

Comment: Thanks @jszakmeister, I'll look into that. I have never heard of quickfix before your answer, looks like it might be useful in other tasks too. But I disagree that I didn't state my purpose. I clearly said "I want to **process** output of this command more, so" in the question.

Comment: Sorry... what I meant was that I didn't understand what processing meant in that context.  Some people say "process" to mean use or view--I'm going to process that information--but it can also mean to manipulate and alter.  It wasn't clear which you meant.  I try not to make too many assumptions since quite a few users are not native English speakers. :-)  All of that said, the quickfix window is very nice, especially in conjunction with `:cnext` and `:cprev` to jump to the next and previous occurrences.